# scrape sector and industry form morningstar

Tags: ruby, watir

I want to scrape the Sector and Industry from Morningstar page. I can see the data and the Watir is also seeing it. But when I try to grab the div it does not return anything.

```
   irb(main):001:0> require 'watir'
=> true

irb(main):008:0> browser= Watir::Browser.new

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49780/devtools/browser/4e473d9e-4818-45ad-8238-587bc931099a
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x..f0e9773de url="data:," title="">
irb(main):006:0> path="http://quote.morningstar.ca/Quicktakes/stock/stock_beta.aspx?t=GOOG&region=USA&culture=en-CA"
=> "http://quote.morningstar.ca/Quicktakes/stock/stock_beta.aspx?t=GOOG&region=USA&culture=en-CA"
irb(main):007:0> goto(path)
irb(main):009:0> browser.goto(path)
[41088:42292:1007/225520.743:ERROR:platform_sensor_reader_win.cc(242)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
=> "http://quote.morningstar.ca/Quicktakes/stock/stock_beta.aspx?t=GOOG&region=USA&culture=en-CA"
irb(main):010:0> browser.text.include?"Sector"  #### CAN FIND THE word sector.
=> true
irb(main):011:0> browser.div(:class=>"sal-dp-panel")  ##### it cannot find the class at all.
=> #<Watir::Div: located: false; {:class=>"sal-dp-panel", :tag_name=>"div"}>
    irb(main):015:0> divs=browser.divs(:class=>"sal-dp-panel")
=> #<Watir::DivCollection:0x000000079722d0 @query_scope=#<Watir::Browser:0xdbd2266a url="http://quote.morningstar.ca/Quicktakes/stock/stock_beta.aspx?t=GOOG&region=USA&culture=en-CA" title="GOOG 1157.35 -0.93 (Alphabet Inc Class C)">, @selector={:class=>"sal-dp-panel", :tag_name=>"div"}>
irb(main):018:0> divs.count
=> 0
irb(main):019:0> divs.each{|div| puts div.text}
=> []
irb(main):020:0> divs.each{|div| puts "got one"}
=> []
```

[image]

Comment: There may be a chance that it may contain more than one div with the same class so it's returning text of first div which doesn't have any text.

Comment: did more tests as i added to the original code segment. 
irb(main):021:0> divs=browser.divs(:class=>"sal-dp-panel").count
=> 0

Comment: If count is zero then you haven't found any div, that's the problem too. Wait for the text there may be chance you are trying to grasp the value even before page loads properly.

Comment: This is really where I am confused.  I can find the text via code browser.text.include?"Sector" but i am not able to find the div tag that holds this

Comment: Check this `browser.div(:class=>"sal-dp-panel").text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there are no elements on the page with the class "sal-dp-panel". Maybe you meant to get the "sal-dp-pair", which is the div containing the name/value pair?

```
<div class="sal-dp-pair">
  <div class="sal-dp-name ng-binding">Sector</div>
  <div class="sal-dp-value ng-binding">Technology</div>
</div>
```

To scrape the sector and industry, you can find the relevant "sal-dp-name" and then find it's corresponding value (ie following sibling):

```
browser.div(class: 'sal-dp-name', text: 'Sector').following_sibling.text
#=> "Technology"

browser.div(class: 'sal-dp-name', text: 'Industry').following_sibling.text
#=> Internet Content & Information"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong locator

Try below

```
b = Watir::Browser.new 
b.goto 'http://quote.morningstar.ca/Quicktakes/stock/stock_beta.aspx?t=GOOG&region=USA&culture=en-CA'

p b.divs(class: 'sal-dp-name')[7].text

p b.div(text: 'Technology').preceding_sibling.text
```

output

```
"Sector"
"Sector"
```

I have located `Sector` in two different way, second one is more reliable than the first one, because I used `Technology` to locate the `Sector` String.